# How to remove the last row in each group_by?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame and I would like to remove the last row for each name. Could anyone tell me how to do that? Thank you in advance.

```
df <- data.frame(c(500,200,100,600,300,400),c(100,50,2,70,60,90),c("A","A","A","B","C","C"))
colnames(df) <- c("income","tax","name")
#> df
  income tax name
1    500 100    A
2    200  50    A
3    100   2    A
4    600  70    B
5    300  60    C
6    400  90    C
#I have tried like this but I will lost the information about B
library(dplyr)
df$row <- rownames(df)
df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  filter(row != max(row))
#ideal result should be
  income tax name
     500 100    A
     200  50    A
     600  70    B
     300  60    C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After grouping by 'name' `slice` to remove the last row (`-n()`) `if the number of rows is greater than 1 or else keep the full rows

```
df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  slice(if(n() > 1)-n() else row_number())
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   name [3]
#  income   tax name 
#   <dbl> <dbl> <fct>
#1    500   100 A    
#2    200    50 A    
#3    600    70 B    
#4    300    60 C
```

---

Or use a OR (`|`) in `filter`

```
df %>% 
   group_by(name) %>%
   filter(n() == 1 | row_number() < n())
```

Comment: thank you so much, your answer work! Could you tell me how this "slice" and "n()" work?

Comment: @Codezy `slice` takes a numeric index to select those rows and negative index remove that row.  Here `n()` gives the number of rows (per group) or the last row.  By using `-n()`, it removes that.

Comment: @Codezy Thank you.  Glad to help you.  Have a good night to you as well.